Check if any word of a string exists in a column with comma-separated values in mysql
I have this string "I need red budget car".
I have a table where in column keywords I have comma-separated words. I know that I can use find_in_set to search if a specific word (ex.budget or car) exists in that column like this for example:
select * from products where find_in_set('budget',keywords) <> 0

However, I can't find a way to check whether any of the words from the string exist if the keywords column.
Of course, I can separate the string by words and run the above query for each word, but that would increase the execution time, so I am looking for some way to do it in one query.
Update
Maybe I can dynamically create the query and create OR statement for each word of the string, like:
SELECT * FROM products WHERE FIND_IN_SET('I', keywords) OR FIND_IN_SET('need', keywords) OR FIND_IN_SET('a', keywords) OR FIND_IN_SET('budget', keywords) OR FIND_IN_SET('car', keywords)

But there must be a more elegant solution I guess?

Using REPLACE and CONCAT convert your strings to valid JSON arrays then apply JSON_OVERLAPS.

Can you give an example?

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, read and perform #5 and #3.

I have found the best answer for my case. It's a function that you compare one comma-separated list to another, directly inside the select query.
Here is the function you have to add to MySQL
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `FIND_IN_SET_X`(inputList TEXT,targetList TEXT) RETURNS INT(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE limitCount INT DEFAULT 0 ;
  DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0 ;
  DECLARE res INT DEFAULT 0 ;
  DECLARE temp TEXT ;
  SET limitCount = 1 + LENGTH(inputList) - LENGTH(REPLACE(inputList, ',', '')) ;
  simple_loop :
  LOOP
    SET counter = counter + 1 ;
    SET temp = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(inputList, ',', counter),',',- 1) ;
    SET res = FIND_IN_SET(temp, targetList) ;
    IF res > 0 
    THEN LEAVE simple_loop ;
    END IF ;
    IF counter = limitCount 
    THEN LEAVE simple_loop ;
    END IF ;
  END LOOP simple_loop ;
  RETURN res ;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

Then instead of using FIND_IN_SET(), you can use the FIND_IN_SET_X() function that you created.
So the query would be
select * from products where FIND_IN_SET_X('I,need,a,budget,car',keywords) <> 0

I took this function from this post mysql check if numbers are in a comma separated list

Before using FIND_IN_SET() in MySQL you need to know about the following

column contains comma-separated values without any extra spaces
If extra space is there then you should replace with some other characters

SELECT * FROM Products WHERE FIND_IN_SET('budget', REPLACE(keywords, ' ', ',')) > 0;
before  using find_in_Set need to replace space between values with comma-separator works fine.

This is not solving my problem as I have to run the same query for each word in the string. I want to avoid the loop, and just check if any of the words in the string exist in the keyword column.

Now thinking twice, your comment is quite helpful.
